# AWS Storage Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, storage, gateway, hybrid

Is there a way to present onprem storage to AWS EC2 instances without copying to S3 etc.  We have a storage array in our DC, I want to carve up LUNs and present them to our apps running on EC2 instances in AWS, using storage gateway.  Can someone suggest if this is possible at all?  I don't want to pay for AWS EBS volumes, when I have plenty of storage available with me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to do this with Storage Gateway - it serves as an interface between your local network and S3.

If you want to expose your local disk to EC2, you will need to run a file share (NFS or Samba), set up a VPN or Direct Connect between your data center and your AWS VPC, and then mount the exported volumes on your EC2 instance.

If you don't want to pay for any EBS volumes, you should look for instance storage based AMIs.  Keep in mind that you cannot stop these instances - you can only terminate them.

Answer (score 0):

According to latest AWS cloud architecture and infrastructure developments, AWS cloud resources can access on premise storages. Not only computing instances but also AWS managed SaaS can do it same. Standard protocols such as NFS, SMB and iSCSI available and you can mount AWS computing instances to remote storage through site-to-site VPN.